# What is the use of references of objects in Java?

Tags: java, object, reference

Why we use references for objects in java?

Snippet one:

```
Computer comp  = new Computer();
```

Snippet two:

```
Computer comp;
comp = new Computer();
```

Why we use references if we can make a object like shown in snippet one both are same and do the same things?

Comment: Are you intentionally using different types - `Computer` and `computer`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [References in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529084/references-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result from both of the snippets is the same.

We have two operations: *declaration* and *initialization*.

In snippet one the two operations are applied in one statement:

```
Computer comp     =    new Computer();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 declaration           initialization
```

This means that you will have a variable on the stack, called `comp`, which will point to a value in the  heap `new Computer()`.

Snippet two does the same thing, but the operations are split:

```
Computer comp;   <-- declaration
comp = new Computer();  <-- initialization
```

Comment: what is the reason for splitting the declaration and initialization  in two parts, if we can do this in one statement and both makes the same sense.

Comment: @Yogesh, because sometimes, for example, we'd like to define a variable outside a block (loop, method, etc.) in order to use it after the block has finished.

Comment: for example we have declared a instance variable, and initialized it in a method, then the variable will only be initialized if we call that method

Comment: <code> class os{                                               computer comp;                                                            void windows{ comp =  new pc; }                             void mac{  comp = new macbook;  }                                                       }</code>                                                           if we call the windows method then the object is a pc, and if the mac method is called then object is a macbook.  Is it a correct example

Answer (score 0):

You simply may not know what to assign at `Computer comp` declaration time.

Answer (score 0):

In both methods,there is a reference variable and an object.

```
Computer comp = new Computer();
```

Here,`comp` is the reference variable and `new Computer()` is the object which is created.This object is then assigned to the reference variable `comp`.

```
Computer comp;
comp = new Computer();
```

Here also,`comp` is the reference variable and `new Computer()` is the object which is created.This object is then assigned to the reference variable `comp`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet you are declaring a reference variable and initializing it in the same statement.
In the second snippet you split the declaration and initialization.

Sometimes it makes sense to split them, since the instance referred by the variable may be initialized in different ways (using different constructors or constructor arguments) depending on some conditions.

If the reference variable is local to some block, you must give it some initial value before first accessing it (either `null` or an actual instance reference), or the code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, it makes a big difference when loading as class.

Example 1:

```
class MyObj {
   private ComplexClass cc = new ComplexClass();
}
```

Example 2:

```
class MyObj {
   private ComplexClass cc;

   MyObj() {
      cc = new ComplexClass();
   }
}
```

In Example 1 'cc' will be initialized, if 'MyObj' is loading by the class loader.

In Example 2 'cc' will be initialized, if 'MyObj' will be initialized.

For classes with many complex properties, it makes a difference in terms of the usage of the Java-heap.

Please correct me if I'm wrong!